# error: unknown file type '.hpp' in distutils extension module

Tags: c++, python, swig, distutils, python-extensions

I'm trying to generate Python bindings for some C++ code using SWIG.

It created some `blah_wrap.cxx` and `blah.py` files.

I then created this `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

ext = Extension('_ev3',
    sources=[
        'ev3_serial_wrap.cxx',
        'ev3_serial.hpp'
        'ev3_motor_wrap.cxx',
        'ev3_motor.hpp'
        'ev3_i2c_wrap.cxx',
        'ev3_i2c.hpp'
        'ev3_analog_wrap.cxx',
        'ev3_analog.hpp'
    ],
    language='c++',
)

setup (name = 'evpy',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "Pepijn de Vos",
       description = """
       An EV3 API.
       """,
       ext_modules = [ext],
       packages=['evpy'],
       )
```

But then I get

```
$ python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_ev3' extension
error: unknown file type '.hpp' (from 'ev3_analog.hpp')
```

`.hpp` is a pretty standard C++ extensions right? Why not `.cpp`? I don't know, the author of the original code put the implementation in his header files.

Comment: `distutils` will use SWIG to generate the `_wrap.cxx` when you use the command `python setup.py build_ext`. I don't think it's required to include the `_wrap.cxx` files in your `sources` list, but this is probably not the source of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure header files are supposed to go in the sources argument, and not in another like headers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter "include_dirs".  See the documentation for Extension here:
http://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html
http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `.h` and `.hpp` do the same jobs, try to change the extension to `.h`, your python script might not know `.hpp` files (which is not a shame)...